# Enable Codeigniter Query Builder

Tags: php, codeigniter, odbc

I am using CodeIgniter v3.1.4 and I'd like to take advantage of Query Builder.

As far as I can tell, all I need to do is set `$query_builder` to TRUE in `config/database.php`, which I have done. But, when I try to use the class, I get the following error:

> Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::where()

I am using Wiredesignz' HMVC implementation, which overrides (among other things) the Loader class, through which the `$query_builder` variable is transferred.

I'm a little surprised that this feature can be toggled on/off via a global variable, rather than directly through db config data. Nevertheless, I have tried toggling it on and off without success.

Not sure that it's relevant but I'm using the ODBC driver and my query looks like this:

```
$this->db->where('userid', $userid)->set($data);
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: show your model's construct method...

Comment: do you have php_pdo_odbc turned on in your php.ini?

Comment: Yes, and I can successfully query my database when I compose my own queries. The point of failure is in the implementation of the Query Builder class - as far as I can tell, CI_DB fails to extend CI_DB_query_builder so my driver ends up missing many useful methods.

Comment: **model construct method**
`public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
     $this->table_name = 'web_appusers';
}`

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon the same issue today when trying to transition to odbc.

In CI 3.1.0 they dropped support for ODBC on their querybuilder (which -in my opinion- defeats the reasons for using the QB in the first place)

The reason is that their implementation caused a SQL injection vulnerability; however they seem to have no plans on fixing it; but rather disable QB entirely for odbc, locking you in.

source: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65803.html

"upgrade notes": http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_310.html

Github issue stating unlikeliness of a fix: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/5197

Answer (score 0):

Check for the following option in application/config/database.php:

`$query_builder = TRUE;`

`$query_builder` should be `true` if you want to use query builder classes of CI

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I guess, the thread owner already tried that since they're mentioning it in the question.